# Set User Object in session using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to set the `User` Object which contains the details of the user into session in my Spring Application.

I would like to use this session object when I would like to retrieve the details of the logged in user on various JSP pages.

I am using Spring 3 and Spring Security 3

I would like to set the User object in the session from my custom authentication class which is not a controller

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have *some* implementation of [`UserDetailsService`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) class. You can return any `User` object implementing [`UserDetails`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetails.html) from [`loadUserByUsername()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html#loadUserByUsername%28java.lang.String%29). This object is then automatically placed in your HTTP session. It can then be retrieved with:

```
User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.
    getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Spring Security handles everything you need automatically.