# Storing user object in session in Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I would like to know how to correctly store and retrieve my user in the session via Spring Security. I am using an AuthenticationManager. So far I am using the following approach which I know isn't the cleanest

```
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/myAccount", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void myAccount(HttpServletRequest request){

        //Verify Logged in user
        User user = null;
        UserProfile loggedinUser = (UserProfile) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

        if(loggedinUser != null){
            user = userService.loadUserByUsername(loggedinUser.getUsername());
        }

        //Store User in session
        Session session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("user", user);


    }
}
```

I took a look at the answer here: [Set User Object in session using Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187501/set-user-object-in-session-using-spring)

But I don't fully understand how I should implement it. Could I possibly implement my User class like this

```
public class User implements UserDetails {
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String email;
......
}
```

And then modify my controller like this

```
public class UserController {


    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/myAccount", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void myAccount(){

        User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.
    getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    }
}
```

From my understanding, Spring will automatically load my custom User from the database and store it in the session?

Thanks

Comment: It really depends on how you're handling the login process. If you're implementing `AuthenticationProvider` or `AuthenticationManager`, then putting the principal into the context is done for you. Note also that you can just use `@AuthenticationPrincipal`, and Spring MVC will pass the principal to the controller method as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, i'm using the AuthenticationManager.